# Spring Boot: Dynamic ServletPath and ContextPath for Embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7, embedded-tomcat-8

I'd like to modify the Embedded Tomcat, so that I can programmatically modify the incoming request:

- Original Input: `http://localhost:8080/webapp/foo` with contextPath =  and servletPath = `/webapp/foo`
- Modified: contextPath = `/webapp` and servletPath = `/foo`

I can't do it within Spring itself, because the Session Cookie Path is getting set by Tomcat.

And I can't use a static `contextPath` because this is a multi tenancy app.

---

I tried to use

```
TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = ...;
tomcat.addContextValves(new ValveBase() {
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ...
    }
});
```

but I wasn't able to set the `servletPath` there.

---

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve, but have you tried setting this property in the application.properties file:
server.context-path=/webapp

This will put your whole application in the /webapp context path

Comment: As I said: I want tomcat to **always** strip the first part of the `servletPath` and set that as `contextPath`. The application runs at tomcat's root, though `contextPath` is `/` and `servletPath` is whatever request comes in. `...` the main reason why I need it, is the Session Cookie: Whenever Spring Security creates a Session Cookie, it delegates that work to tomcat. So tomcat is setting the `Path=` part of the Cookie, and its value depends on the `contextPath`. There's no way to set it from within Spring.